# LinkedList in Java: Why it directly implements List when it indirectly from extended class

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

I see the following class hierarch, for `LinkedList` in Java.

```
public interface Collection<E>
extends Iterable<E>


public abstract class AbstractCollection<E>
extends Object
implements Collection<E>


public abstract class AbstractList<E>
extends AbstractCollection<E>
implements List<E>

public abstract class AbstractSequentialList<E>
extends AbstractList<E>

public class LinkedList<E>
extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

Observing this hierarchy, why `LinkedList` need to mention `implements List<E>` when it is indirectly coming from `AbstractList<E>`.

Is there any reason to do so?

**EDIT**

Screenshot[image] of the actual code (from rt.jar)

Comment: It does not. Javadoc however **documents** it. Because it is documentation tool.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: It does in actual source code, adding the snippet of code.

Comment: The dupe answers the equivalent question for `ArrayList`; the reasoning equally applies to `LinkedList`.

Comment: Sure, let me check. I guess @Hari Menon provided a plausible reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it has no impact in terms of language semantics in this case. I imagine they just put it to make it clearer that it implements `List` as well, without the developer having to traverse the full hierarchy.